# How can I make the data point in the list into columns?

Tags: r, parsing, html-parsing

I am facing a problem with data transformation. I have two vectors with 5 data points.

```
parameters <- c("Type of offer", "House", "Number of floors", "Area", "Heating")

[1] "Type of offer"    "House"            "Number of floors"
[4] "Area"             "Heating"

values <- c(""from agent", "panel, 1997 г.", "10", "255 sq. m", "central"

# [1] "from agent"     "panel, 1997 г." "10"             "255 sq. m"      "central"
```

What should I do to combine them in a way that it looks like this?

```
  type_of_offer   house               ...
1 from agent      panel, 1997 г.      ...
```

I am doing parsing, so it takes the data in the list format, to be honest. Some tables has 5 variables, some has 10 variables. I don't know how to extract them when the tables come in two separate rows, and also ultimately put each of them into columns with iteration when the number of the rows do not match.

Comment: `setNames(values, parameters)`?

Comment: Yes, it did. Thanks, Allan Cameron.